# Find a generator of the two ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra

- An element $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $(f(x))=(x^4+x^2+1, x^3-1)$.

I think this question is similar to finding the generator of subgroup of integers. All we have to do is to try to find a common divisor of the two polynomials, namely, $x^4+x^2+1$ and $x^3-1$. In this case, we can find such a common divisor since $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$. Therefore, $f(x)=x^2+x+1$.

- An element $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $(f(x))=(2, x)$.

I think similar argument should work here. But it seems that this time, we cannot find an appropriate common divisor for the two. Therefore, there is not a single generator. Is this a maximal ideal, please? In addition, if we change the ring to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then the generator is the unit ideal since there exists an inverse for 2. Right?

Comment: Yes, all true. And $(2,x)$ is indeed a maximal ideal of ${\mathbb{Z}[x]}$. Note that ${\mathbb{Z}[x]}/(2,x) \cong {\mathbb Z}/2$.

Comment: One other remark: in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, any two elements still have a greatest common divisor, except that you won't always be able to write it as a linear combination of the two elements.

Comment: I am wondering whether I can also say $(x^4+x^2+1, x^3-1) $ is an ideal if now I consider two variable ring $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$? Then this is not a principal ideal from previous reasoning. Right?